# A relation $R$ on $A$ which is symmetric and total but not transitive.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

**Exercise:**

> Let $A = \left\{ a,b,c,d,e\right\}$. Find a relation $R$ on $A$ which is summetric and total but not transitive.

**Question:**

We want to find a relation $R$ on $A$, namely $R \subseteq A \times A$, such as:

1. *Symmetric:* $\forall \langle x, y \rangle \in R$ then also $\langle y, x \rangle \in R$,
2. *Total:* $\forall x \neq y \in A$, it is $\langle x, y \rangle \in R$ or $\langle y,x \rangle \in R$,
3. *Not transitive*: For some $\langle x,y\rangle$ and $\langle y,z\rangle \in R$, it's NOT $\langle x,z \rangle \in R$.

By "playing" around with such small sets, sooner or later one can find such a relation (or for example a total and reflexive but not transitive).

What I want to ask, though, is there any clever way of handling such problems?

Comment: What you have written for "not transitive" makes it seem that one needs it to hold that for *every* x,y,z for which it holds that xRy and yRz, then it does not hold that xRz. This is not so, all you need for not transitive is that there exist three particular x,y,z such that xRy and yRz but xRz does not hold *for just this one choice of x,y,z* [rather than for all such choices.

Comment: @coffeemath Agreed and edited accordingly. Apart from that, any recommendations on a solution?

Answer (score 1):

From conditions 1 and 2 together we can show that for all $x \neq y$ we have *both* $xRy$ and $yRx.$ So we are forced to have any distinct items related. However that does not force any relations of type $xRx$ to hold. So what happens if we simply don't include any $xRx$? Then our relation $R$ consists of the pairs $$(a,b),(a,c),(a,d),(a,e),\\ (b,a),(b,c),(b,d),(b,e),\\ (c,a),(c,b),(c,d),(c,e),\\ (d,a),(d,b),(d,c),(d,e),\\ (e,a),(e,b),(e,c),(e,d).$$
This is not transitive, because e.g. it includes the pairs $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ but fails to include $(a,a).$  [Keep in mind that in "xRy and yRz implies xRz" nothing is implied about x,y,z being distinct.]

For total and reflexive but not transitive one would *require* all the xRx. But then since one may choose to omit one of each pair of two aRb, bRa types it would be easy to add pairs to make it total but not transitive.

[if anyone read this, before my last word was "reflexive" rather than the right term "transitive".]

Comment: So by picking a *random* relation with properties 1 and 2, one has a $\frac{31}{32}$ chance  of success for property 3!   :)